# How to close a chunk of Lua code

Tags: c++, lua

I wonder if it's possible to only close a chuck of Lua code loaded with `luaL_dostring` so all the variables inside the chunk can be freed accordingly.

Here's my simple example:

```
lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
luaL_openlibs(L);
luaL_dostring(L, "a = 2"); // Script A
//How close the script A here?
luaL_dostring(L, "print(a)"); // Script B
lua_close(L);
```

This code prints `2` when I run it but I wonder if it's possible to somehow close(or free) only the firstly loaded chunk from the memory so  it prints `nil`.

Comment: Make a new Lua state? (You can `lua_close` the old one if you don't need it any more, I assume.) The fact that `a == 2` is stored in `L`; if there's no more `L`, no more  `a`.

Comment: @Amadan I don't want to make a new Lua state.

Comment: Then I don't understand what you want? Either you want to have the state where `a` has been set to `2`, or you don't, not sure what the third option is. (Basically, if you say "I don't want solution X" you need to also say why X is not good for you, or any answerer will be stuck with "well, what now?")

Comment: I'm asking if I can kinda undo the execution of `luaL_dostring` so it can be freed from the memory. All I know is to assign `nil` to each variable. But I wonder if there's any better option. (I want a better solution because assigning `nil` to every single variable is a pain)

Comment: @Amadan I don't want to close the Lua state because it will free other variables (e.g. variables of Script B) from the memory too. I'm asking if I can only free a chunk of code loaded with `luaL_dostring` from memory. I hope you understand what I mean.

Comment: There is no separate chunk of memory loaded by `luaL_dostring`. It simply changes the Lua state passed to it. There's two things you can do: explicitly unset variables you have set in order to free them, or you could clone your Lua state before the script B, so you can pretend it never happened.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Roughly speaking you want to sandbox script A, i.e. run it with a different global environment than script B.  This can easily be done by backing up the global table into the registry and replacing it with an empty table (optionally populate the empty table with whatever you need inside the sandbox).  After script A is finished you simply retrieve the old global table from the registry and make it the current global table again.

Apart from that I recommend reducing the usage of globals to an absolute minimum.  In fact, I never use any global variables when I write Lua code.  Usually I record information in local tables and pass these around.  This is probably a more [functional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Functional_programming) style of writing Lua.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <lua.hpp>

int main() {
    lua_State *L = luaL_newstate();
    luaL_openlibs(L);

    // START SANDBOX

    // Push the global table into the registry
    lua_pushglobaltable(L);
    lua_setfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "globals");

    // Push a new empty table and make it the global table
    lua_newtable(L);
    lua_rawseti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, LUA_RIDX_GLOBALS);

    // Script A
    if (luaL_dostring(L, "a = 2") != 0) {
        std::cerr << "lua:" << lua_tostring(L, -1) << '\n';
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }

    // Retrieve the global table from the registry and make it the global table
    lua_getfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "globals");
    lua_rawseti(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, LUA_RIDX_GLOBALS);

    // Optional: Remove the global table from the registry
    lua_pushnil(L);
    lua_setfield(L, LUA_REGISTRYINDEX, "globals");

    // END SANDBOX

    // Script B
    if (luaL_dostring(L, "print(a)") != 0) {
        std::cerr << "lua:" << lua_tostring(L, -1) << '\n';
        lua_pop(L, 1);
    }
    lua_close(L);
}
```

```
$ clang++ -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -I /usr/include/lua5.2/ test.cpp -llua5.2
$ ./a.out 
nil
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir. It works like a charm. Since you've recommended not to use globals if possible, I wonder what you think about this design to free a chunk of Lua code. Please take a look at my other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51398266/how-to-properly-create-a-free-function-in-lua